# Can we define PHP session variables in one place?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Can we define the PHP session variables in one place inside some function or variable so that we can use that across the application?

Like this:

```
$abc=$_SESSION['my_session'];

$abc['name']='john';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read on [references in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) as this is very basic question.

```
//ensure my_session exists and is an array
$_SESSION['my_session'] = isset($_SESSION['my_session']) ? $_SESSION['my_session'] : array();

//assign by reference
$abc = &$_SESSION['my_session'];

$abc['name'] = 'john';
```

Note that `$abc` will be available only in current scope, so to use it inside a function you'll have to use `global` keyword. That's a bit "dirty" so you should probably use functions instead of this.